# How to assign value to a variable from a select statement inside stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure and for debugging purposes, I want to know what value is getting returned, in order to do that I have created a table and logging the value returned from a query but I am not sure on how to get the value in that select statement for loggin.

My stored procedure (modified for demonstration):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SID INT 

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 
            SL.[Column1], SL.[Column2], SL.[Column3], 
            SMD.[Column4], SMD.[Column5]
            (some more logic)               

        BEGIN 
            DECLARE @ProcedureName6 NVARCHAR(168) = 'dbo.MYSP',
                    @ErrorMessage6 NVARCHAR(4000)

            SELECT @ErrorMessage6 = 'SID is:' +  CAST(@SID AS VARCHAR)

            EXEC [Log].[ErrorLoger] @ProcedureName6, @ErrorMessage6
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        //Some Logic
    END CATCH
END
```

I actually want `SL.[Column2]` to be set in `@SID` for logging.

Comment: what if your query returns multiple rows. How do you intent to set the value of `SL.[Column2]` in `@SID` ?

Comment: Just start with ... -->> SELECT SL.[Column1], ... thru (some more logic)  and return the columns.  Run it in SSMS, and look at the results in the lower window.

Comment: @Squirrel That might be the case, but for this particular query, only 1 record will be returned.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple result return from the query, you can insert the result to a temp table. From there, get the required value from the temp table and execute the ErorrLogger SP.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP ( Column1, Column2, . . .)
SELECT SL.[Column1]
        ,SL.[Column2]
        ,SL.[Column3]
        ,SMD.[Column4]
        ,SMD.[Column5]
      (Some more logic)     

-- Get the value of @SID from temp table
SELECT @SID = Column2 FROM #TEMP

-- Return the result
SELECT  Column1, Column2, . . .
FROM    #TEMP

....
EXEC [Log].[ErrorLoger] @ProcedureName6
                       ,@ErrorMessage6
```

You may also use multiple variable (each for one column) to hold the result of your query. Provided that the query only return single row